# Remove Blank Rows in excel using vbscript

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript

We get excel file from source system and we need to convert it to CSV. 
Sometimes, last line of excel file we get empty rows. We need to delete that row before the file is placed as CSV. I use the below code for doing this conversion but it doesn’t work all the time.It still retains that empty rows which causes problem when converted to CSV and last line of the CSV just shows commas.

Below is the script

```
Dim StrSourcePathFile, StrDestPathFile

set xlApp = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

StrSourcePathFile = "c:\temp\var31.XLSX"

StrDestPathFile = "c:\temp\var31.csv"

xlApp.Workbooks.Open StrSourcePathFile
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

If xlApp.ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Text = "" Then
xlApp.ActiveSheet.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
End If


If xlApp.ActiveSheet.Rows((xlApp.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)).Text = "" Then
xlApp.ActiveSheet.Rows((xlApp.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)).EntireRow.Delete
End If 

xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs StrDestPathFile,6

xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true


xlapp.Quit()


Set fso = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure activesheet is always the one you want? Have you tried with `.value` instead of `.text`? Also, are you sure the last row is indeed blank and not holding spaces that look blank?

Comment: yes , I need activesheet. I tried replace .text to .value, I get runtime error. Yes last row contains blank for sure. when converted to CSV, last row just contains only commas which means If you the excel has 5 columns, 5 commas are placed at end of the file.

Comment: Instead of xlApp.ActiveSheet.UsedRange , how can I give a range like A1:Z10 ?

Comment: This is quiet strange that code is working fine when I save the excel first and then do the conversion. It is able to delete empty row in the excel. This is the modified code.

Can anyone help me on the reason behind this problem Or any better way to handle it ?


strPathExcel1 = StrSourcePathFile
Set objWB = objExcel1.Workbooks.Open(strPathExcel1)
Set objSheet1 = objWB.Worksheets(1)


objWB.Save
objWB.Close
objExcel1.Quit